# How to group two DOM elements into one in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Let's say I want to group div1 and div2 elements to a variable c

```
var a = jQuery(".div1");
var b = jQuery(".div2");
```

I tried to use this command

```
var c = jQuery(a,b);
```

But then variable c only gives me elements from variable b

How can I get both elements to my variable c

Comment: [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a array

```
var c = jQuery([a[0],b[0]]);
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/dzoyzv02/

Comment: That is what I was searching for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Simply combine the selector string:

```
var c = jQuery(".div1, .div2")
```

Comment: This is a good solution but I need variables because i use some filters

Comment: then use `toArray()` after wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `add()` method to achieve this:

```
var $a = $('.div1');
var $b = $('.div2');
var $c = $a.add($b);
```

Or simply:

```
var $a = $('.div1');
var $c = $a.add('.div2');
```